# Problemas com Sintaxe de Objeto no Json?

Tags: json

Estou com problema na **sintaxe** do **shoppingsObj**, porque está dando este erro?

> Expected a JSON object, array or literal.

```
shoppingsObj = {

    "shoppings": [
        { "nome": "Bangu Shopping", "licenseKey":"0", "acessKey":"0", "secretKey":"0", "latitude1":["-22.879832"], "latitude2":["-22.877738"], "longitude1:":["-43.468601"], "longitude2:":["-43.465978"] },
        { "nome": "Boulevard Shopping Campos", "licenseKey":"0", "acessKey":"0", "secretKey":"0", "latitude1":["-21.755484"], "latitude2":["-21.753139"], "longitude1:":["-41.350870"], "longitude2:":["-41.346417"] }
    ]

 }
```

Comment: Seu `JSON` possui um formato inválido. Você está manipulando-o com `javascript`?

Comment: Ola Thiago. Isto vem de onde? Requisição Ajax? Esta usando jQuery ou outro framework? Você escreveu isso manualmente no teu .js? Poderia explicar exatamente como obteve este JSON?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, estou manipulando com o java para Android. Preciso criar um objeto que é o shoppingsObj e depois fazer o seguinte shoppingsObj.latitude[] = "";

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento escrevi aqui acima agora.

Comment: É possivel postar o objeto inteiro, ou pelo menos um pouco mais completo?

Comment: Perai, então esta escrevendo em Java então? Creio que esta sintaxe só vai funcionar com o pacote para Json e fazendo o Parse de uma string. Poderia dar detalhes do código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> estou manipulando com o java para Android. Preciso criar um objeto que é o shoppingsObj e depois fazer o seguinte shoppingsObj.latitude[] = ""

Se estás a consumir esse `JSON`, o formato válido para o seu caso é:

```
{
    "shoppings": [{
            "nome": "Bangu Shopping",
            "licenseKey": "0",
            "acessKey": "0",
            "secretKey": "0",
            "latitude1": ["-22.879832"],
            "latitude2": ["-22.877738"],
            "longitude1:": ["-43.468601"],
            "longitude2:": ["-43.465978"]
        },
        {
            "nome": "Boulevard Shopping Campos",
            "licenseKey": "0",
            "acessKey": "0",
            "secretKey": "0",
            "latitude1": ["-21.755484"],
            "latitude2": ["-21.753139"],
            "longitude1:": ["-41.350870"],
            "longitude2:": ["-41.346417"]
        }
    ]

}
```

Mas para obter o resultado, como você exemplificou não é possível. Você possui um objeto `shoppings` que contém um `array`, você terá de acessar um dos índices ou iterar sobre ele.

Um exemplo seria:

```
shoppingsObj.shoppings[0].nome // retornará "Bangu Shopping"
shoppingsObj.shoppings[0].latitude1 // retornará "-22.879832"
```

Comment: obrigado. Agora eu preciso saber como eu consumo isso no java para Android, irei criar um tópico perguntando isto.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
{"shoppings": [
    { "nome": "Bangu Shopping", "licenseKey":"0", "acessKey":"0", "secretKey":"0", "latitude1":["-22.879832"], "latitude2":["-22.877738"], "longitude1:":["-43.468601"], "longitude2:":["-43.465978"] },
    { "nome": "Boulevard Shopping Campos", "licenseKey":"0", "acessKey":"0", "secretKey":"0", "latitude1":["-21.755484"], "latitude2":["-21.753139"], "longitude1:":["-41.350870"], "longitude2:":["-41.346417"] }
]}
```

Note que esse json é um objeto que tem uma lista de objetos chamada `shoppings` então para vc mudara a latitude do primeiro shopping, vc teria que fazer:

```
shoppingsObj.shoppings[0].latitude = ...
```

Comment: "shoppingsObj" não é uma String é um objeto.

Comment: preciso dele para fazer o seguinte shoppingJb.latitude[1] = "";

Comment: Mas no exemplo que te dei ele é exatamente um objeto. Em q linguagem vc esta fazendo?